# Laravel validate a field in an array of arrays

Tags: laravel

`selected_products` is an array of arrays

```
^ array:7 [▼
  "selected_products" => array:2 [▼
    0 => array:2 [▼
      "id" => 2
      "quantity" => 10
    ]
    1 => array:2 [▼
      "id" => 1
      "quantity" => 22
    ]
  ]
]
```

I'm trying to validate the quantity of each product if greater than or equal to the quantity in stock I want to get a **Out of stock**

This is what I tried so far

```
'selected_products.*.quantity' => [function ($input, $item) {
    return $item > 100;
}],
```

Comment: Why are you using a function to check if the number is > 100? Integer validation is one of the most basic rules there is. https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#rule-min

Comment: Shouldn't you include some information about how you know if an item is in stock? Pretty hard to make that solution without that.

Comment: @miken32 I checked if the number is greater than 100 just to see if the validation works but it doesn't. Then I'll find the product with the `id` in the `selected_products` array and check if the `quantity` in the `selected_products` array is greater than the quantity in `Product::find($id)->stock->quantity` and if it is I want the validation to return *Out of stock*

Comment: @mrhn Product and stock is a one to one relationship. Here's my stock function in the Product model  
```public function stock() { return $this->morphOne(Stock::class, 'stockable'); }```